# Powershell IIS Get-Binding list export-csv issue System.Object

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to get a script that lists the IIS site name, FilePath and Bindings, which works fine expect when I export-csv.  When doing so I get System.Object[] in my results for the path and not sure how to correct this.

```
Get-WebBinding | % {
$names = $_.ItemXPath -replace '(?:.*?)name=''([^'']*)(?:.*)', '$1'
$path = get-website $names | select-object physicalpath
New-Object psobject -Property @{
    Binding = $_.bindinginformation.Split(":")[-1]
    path = $path
    Name = $names
}    } | export-csv c:\test1.csv -notypeinformation
```

I actually created a more elegant solution for this

Solution:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$hostname = hostname
$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites
$date = (Get-Date).ToString('MMddyyyy')
foreach ($Site in $Websites) {
    $Binding = $Site.bindings
    [string]$BindingInfo = $Binding.Collection
    [string[]]$Bindings = $BindingInfo.Split(" ")#[0]
    $i = 0
    $status = $site.state
    $path = $site.PhysicalPath
    $fullName = $site.name
    $state = ($site.name -split "-")[0]
    $Collection = ($site.name -split "-")[1]
    $status = $site.State
    $anon = get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/AnonymousAuthentication -Name Enabled -PSPath IIS:\sites -Location $site.name | select-object Value
    $basic = get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/BasicAuthentication -Name Enabled -PSPath IIS:\ -location $site.name | select-object Value
    Do{
        if( $Bindings[($i)] -notlike "sslFlags=*"){
            [string[]]$Bindings2 = $Bindings[($i+1)].Split(":")
            $obj = New-Object PSObject
            $obj | Add-Member Date $Date
            $obj | Add-Member Host $hostname
            $obj | Add-Member State $state
            $obj | Add-Member Collection $Collection
            $obj | Add-Member SiteName $Site.name
            $obj | Add-Member SiteID $site.id
            $obj | Add-member Path $site.physicalPath
            $obj | Add-Member Protocol $Bindings[($i)]
            $obj | Add-Member Port $Bindings2[1]
            $obj | Add-Member Header $Bindings2[2]
            $obj | Add-member AuthAnon $Anon.value
            $obj | Add-member AuthBasic $basic.value
            $obj | Add-member Status $status
            $obj #| export-csv "c:\temp\$date-$hostname.csv" -Append -notypeinformation
            $i=$i+2
        }
        else{$i=$i+1}
    } while ($i -lt ($bindings.count))
}
```

Comment: `path = -join $path`

Comment: I had tried that but no joy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because CSV output is really crappy at nested objects. If you take a look at your code, your "path" attribute is basically a "slice" of the websiteobject. What you want to do is probably expand out that variable so that you get back the actual value (see example below). This is one of those times where 2 minutes of debugging in the ISE can be really helpful!

```
Get-WebBinding | ForEach-Object {
    $names = $_.ItemXPath -replace '(?:.*?)name=''([^'']*)(?:.*)', '$1'
    $path = get-website $names | select-object -expandproperty physicalpath
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Binding = $_.bindinginformation.Split(":")[-1]
        path = $path
        Name = $names
    }    
    }| export-csv c:\test1.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Unfortunately no dice with that either.  I gathered as well that I need it to be an object and that is where I am failing this.  Trying to debug now.

Comment: Actually this seems to work on my desktop powershell Windows 8.1, but not on the server powershell on Windows 2008, thoughts on why that could be?

Comment: Hard to say. Debug it and just step thru it line by line.